# Manually split and distribute a large tensor for distributed computing with PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, distributed-computing

AFAIK, the simplest way to do the distributed training (multiple modes) with Pytorch is something like:

```
sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(train_data)
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, sampler=sampler)
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).cuda()

for data, target in data_loader:
    out = model(data)
    ...
```

But what if I already have a large tensor data in hand and would like to split and distribute it and get the same output as the above snippet? Specifically,

```
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).cuda()
data = do_sth_fuct(data)
out = model(data)
```

Is there a PyTorch API to do so? Otherwise, what is the best way to achieve it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

It's non-trivial if you talk about convolutional networks with spatial inputs in general. Suppose you already have a batch size = 1: How would the total spatial output then look like? Think of an output's receptive field, which is larger than one of your split tensor "chunks" as input and how you would need to combine different chunk forward/backward results. That's why "data parallelism" most easily is achieved along the batch dimension. For a combination with model parallelism often "pipeline parallelism" is preferred in order to avoid drastically reduced speed.

Check out these for further information:

- "Parallel and Distributed Training" tutorials at https://pytorch.org/tutorials/index.html
- https://www.pytorchlightning.ai/
- https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairscale/